# Prevent Jest from printing snapshot diffs

Tags: node.js, jestjs

This is how I currently invoke Jest in my project:

```sh
NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/jest \
  --silent --watchAll=false --runInBand \
  --config=jest.config.js
```

I now want to run Jest *without* printing all the snapshot diffs. I still want to see error messages, console output, test success/failure, etc. I just want it to stop printing the snapshot diffs.

I am debugging something that is generating obviously-incorrect output (as reflected in the snapshots), and it is printing huge piles of diffs that are meaningless to me, because I *know* that they are wrong.

This is the `jest.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  clearMocks: true,
  testMatch: ['**/tests/**/*.spec.[jt]s?(x)'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/tests/setup.js',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/tests/tearDown.js',
  transform: {
    '\\.(gql|graphql)$': '@jagi/jest-transform-graphql',
    '\\.js$': 'jest-esm-transformer'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a custom reporter, such as [jest-summary-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-summary-reporter) (that will print a summary at the end of the test run) and remove the `default` reporter.

1. Install `npm install jest-summary-reporter`
2. Configure your `jest.config.js`

```js
{
  reporters: ['default', 'jest-summary-reporter'],
}
```

remove the `default` part if you don't want the snapshot output (or progress as the test is running), keep it in there if you *do* want it.